# How do I determine minimum steps to visit k leave node of a rooted tree?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, tree

The algorithm is about to visit k leave nodes and return back to root node in minimum steps!!

[image]

Think it is as A person standing at Point 2 and he/she wants to visit k leaves of the tree in minimum steps and back to Point 2.

For k=3 path can be like

2-> "3" ->2->1-> "0" ->1-> "5" ->1->2 (here 3,0,5 are leaves) 
So we visited 3 leves..

Answer: 8

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming ​ ​

Comment: Can you describe more?

Comment: Last problem Facebook Hacker cup 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another bottom-up dynamic program on a rooted tree.

For each subtree, we compute the cost of visiting at least `j` leaves for `j in 0…k`, as a list. If the subtree is a single leaf, then this list is `[0, 0, ∞, ∞, …, ∞]`, where `∞` denotes infinity, representing an infeasible leaf quantity. Otherwise, we compute the list for each child, increase all of the entries except the first in each list by `2`, and then reduce by convolution. To convolve two lists `A` and `B` is to compute `[min {A[i] + B[j-i]: i in 0…j}: j in 0…k]`. Return the `k` entry for the root.

This is `O(n k^2)`-time.

Comment: This problem may come from an ongoing [contest](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problem/1525154397757404/)

Comment: @PhamTrung Sigh. Per personal policy, I'm going to decline to delete because 10k users would have unfair access.

Comment: It is ok, there is no rule against answering this kind of question actually :). IMHO, for 10K users, the chance they don't know how to solve this question is very rare.